# How to pass React Select dropdown value to API in Spring Boot and handle empty string error?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

i'm trying to pass value from React select dropdown to my API

but i'm getting this error :
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot coerce empty String ("")

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function AddFruit() {

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const [values, setValues] = useState([])
    const [fruit, setFruit] = useState({
        name: ''
    })

    const { name } = fruit;

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setFruit({ ...fruit, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/fruits/addFruit', fruit);
        navigate('/fruits');
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/fruits/addFruit')
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then((val) => setValues(val))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-md-6 offset-md-3 border rounded p-4 mt-2 shadow'>
                    <h2 className='text-center m-4'>Add fruit</h2>
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>

                        <select className="form-select mt-5 mb-5" onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}>
                            {
                                values.map((opts, key) => <option key={key}>{opts}</option>)
                            }
                        </select>

                        <button type='submit' className="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
                        <Link className="btn btn-outline-danger mx-2" to={`/fruits`}>Cancel</Link>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```